# How to attach the Character to a moving base

Tags: game-engine, physics

I'm trying to create an elevator, I use Character's physics, Character goes up normally with the elevator, but when descending it goes down slower than the elevator, I already used a script to increase gravity, and Character got heavier than the elevator, however, when he steps in the elevator during the descent, the character bounces. I tried to parent them, but I couldn't get Character to respect the collision of the elevator walls.
And I realized that it is also a problem for me to create a platform that moves, because the Character keeps falling due to the speed.
Thank you for your time, God bless you!

[image: i do]

Comment: When I was using the game engine and came up against this, I had to add an invisible ceiling to elevators and parent them to it.  Not a very elegant solution but it kept their feet on the floor. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for : [walk around and stick to animated objects.blend](https://blenderartists.org/uploads/default/original/4X/b/5/6/b560e4afb82a9db917d6f71cdf800f3ea7c21822.blend)

Original Blender.Artists Thread link [here](https://blenderartists.org/t/walk-and-stick-on-animated-objects-and-planets/1114235)

Video showing the following script in action [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uJKPBdgB0-s)

**THIS SCRIPT DOES NOT WORK WELL WITH CHARACTER PHYSICS!**

**USE DYNAMIC PHYSICS INSTEAD!**

```
# Walk and stick on animated objects and planets v3
# by cotaks

# w,s,a,d and spacebar to move

# able to walk speheres and animated objects:
# like elevators/platforms/planets/beveled cubes/etc.
# when you jump off one of the objects, it will automatically turn +z axis back up

# it' a small script but very adjustable, i added more comments then script itself haha
# have fun with it.

from bge import logic

# from player origin to the floor
heigth_offset = 1.0 

# length of the raycast
# increase this to be able to jump higher before falling of an object 
# (also tweak jump force(brick) and (lower) gravity force)
ray_distance = 0.5 

# creates some player gravity, default 30. 
# (lower ables to jump off objects, higher means you can jump at all sides of the object)
# adjust the player jump force(brick), or adjust the gravity_force, i suggest keeping it 20+
#just experiment around with it till you are statisfied with the results
gravity_force = 30 

def cast_ray(own, vector):

    total_distance = ray_distance + heigth_offset
    return own.rayCast(vector, own, total_distance)


def stick_to_it(cont):

    own = cont.owner

    vector_z    = own.worldPosition - own.worldOrientation.col[2]
    ray_z       = cast_ray(own, vector_z) 

    if ray_z and ray_z[0] is not None:

    # this could be usefull if you use python for movement, stops the sliding
    # if you use this make sure you add a + to line 48 and 49 (so it becomes +=)
    #own.linearVelocity.x = 0
    #own.linearVelocity.y = 0

    # creates some player gravity
    vector = -own.worldOrientation.col[2] * gravity_force
    counter_gravity = own.applyForce(vector,False) 

    # match our speed with the ground speed (add a + before the = if you use the above code)
    own.linearVelocity.x = ray_z[0].linearVelocity.x
    own.linearVelocity.y = ray_z[0].linearVelocity.y

    # align to the floor
    own.alignAxisToVect(ray_z[2],2, 0.3) 

    # counters default gravity stops sliding down from the sides with player friction at 0
    # if you use player (material) friction (default 0.500) then you can remove this line
    own.applyForce((0,0,9.8*own.mass),False)

else:
    # put head (z axis) back up
    own.alignAxisToVect([0,0,2],2, 0.1) 


def update_physics(cont):
    # for the (animated) object(s), or any object that needs to update it
    # (if you want to walk on animated objects(with bones) they need this part)
    # always(true pulse)-python(module)-scriptname.update_physics
    # if you have multiple animated objects, your better of making using for loop here
    # if you use it remove the own.reinstancePhysicsMesh() and uncomment the for loop code
    # with the for loop the animated objects needs a property called: update_physics
    own = cont.owner
    own.reinstancePhysicsMesh()    

#    if not 'update_list' in own:         
#        own['update_list'] = [obj for obj in own.scene.objects if 'update_physics' in obj]
#    
#    for obj in own['update_list']:
#        obj.reinstancePhysicsMesh()
```

Just add this script to your character like that :
[image]